GDB giving "Python not initialized" error message
Trying to install MinGW so I can compile C++ programs in VS Code. Followed the instructions at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw to install everything.
To check if everything was installed correctly I used the commands:
gcc --version
g++ --version
gdb --version

GCC and g++ seem to be working fine, but when I tried to run gdb --version I get the following error:
C:\Users\vaari>gdb --version
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = 'C:\Users\vaari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312'
  PYTHONPATH = 'C:\Users\vaari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312'
  program name = 'C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\python.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  safe_path = 0
  import site = 1
  is in build tree = 0
  stdlib dir = 'C:\Users\vaari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\lib\python3.11'
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\vaari\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\vaari\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:\\Users\\vaari\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\vaari\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\vaari\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312',
    'C:\\Users\\vaari\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\lib\\python311.zip',
    'C:\\Users\\vaari\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\lib\\python3.11',
    'C:\\Users\\vaari\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\lib\\python3.11\\lib-dynload',
  ]
Error occurred computing Python errormessage.
Python not initialized

Have not been able to figure out how to fix it. Tried reinstalling MinGW but it didn't change anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Looks like you have PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH environment variables that don't work well together with this gdb. See this answer.

Thank you, that answer helped me resolve the problem. As suggested there I created a .gdbearlyinit file at C:\Users\vaari\.gdbearlyinit and just put set python ignore-environment on inside the file. After restarting VS Code it now seems to work perfectly.
